# Visual Studio /**/ comment shortcut?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, comments

I want to know how to put the `/**/` comments through shortcut. I know the <kbd>Ctrl+K+C</kbd> shortcut for the `//` comments but it comments the whole line. Sometimes while debugging, I want to do something like "`ref string /* char[] */ lengthValue`" while trying something out.

I want to be able to comment a specific part of a line (not the whole line) through a shortcut e.g in "`string /* char[] */ lengthValue`" i-e comment out only a specific part of a like by shortcut

I am using Visual Studio 2013

Please help

Comment: Actually you can mark part of a line and then use `Ctrl+K+C` in the C++ editor. Sadly, it doesn't work like this in the C# editor.

Comment: Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard > Find Edit.CommentSelection

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I think there is no shortcut key for this purpose in Visual Studio but If you use [`ReSharper`](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>.

Have a look at [`this`](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Coding_Assistance__Comment_Uncomment_Code.html) may be useful as well.

Comment: Visual Studio 2019 [now natively supports this keyboard shortcut](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes#net-productivity) -- _Toggle Block Comment/Uncomment is now available through the keyboard shortcut (Ctrl+Shift+/) or through **Edit > Advanced > Toggle Block Comment**. This command will add or remove block comments depending on what you have selected._

Comment: Very good, thanks. However, VS is does not uncomment multiple blocks with empty lines in between, because it doesn't comments those lines and remains unawre of that.

Comment: To toggle comment, It's `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `/` in Resharper or Rider ( with the keymap of Visual Studio )

Comment: TIL this. Gotta say, though, that sometimes I don't know if a feature is being supplied by VS or by R#.

Answer (score 119):

Visual Studio comment shortcut keys:

Accepted in HTML, C#, JS, CSS etc in Visual Studio.

Line Comment:

To comment: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>

```
//a
//b                      
//c
```

To undo: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd>

```
a
b
c
```

Block Comment:

To comment: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

```
/*a
b
c*/
```

To undo: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

```
a
b
c
```

Comment: **Ctrl+k+c** & **ctrl+k+u** is works for vb.net smoothly but _Ctrl+Shift+/_ is making no change in here. @Muleskinner

Comment: Why is it so complicated

Comment: Absolutely cumbersome.

Comment: @Suza that makes sense, because VB doesn't have block comments, only single-line comments.

Comment: @Muleskinner _Can confirm this works for also vb.net_ -- what, block comments? VB doesn't have block comments.

Comment: Or better change to Visual Studio Code keyboard mapping scheme.

Comment: I want to vote down on this correct answer for it's deadful truth... but I didn't.

Comment: From Visual Studio 2019 on this answer ist better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32426360/2550395

Answer (score 18):

In Visual Studio 2017 RC, simply Select the part of code you want and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> , no need to any extension!

Comment: The OP is asking about Block Comments /**/ not single line comment //.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2017 Community Ctrl + K + C  does do a block quote.

Comment: I can confirm Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise edition also does block comments ( /*...*/) with Ctrl + K, Ctrl + C

Comment: can i customize this?

Answer (score 11):

VS 2019 I did

Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard

Type in `Edit.ToggleBlockComment` and add a keybinding. I chose <kbd>**Shift**</kbd> + <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd> + <kbd>**/**</kbd>.

Or you could put `comment` in the search box of the keyboard section and look at all your comment keybinding shortcut options.

Comment: Dont see any Tools tab. Where is it?

Comment: @Čamo if you don't have the Tools tab somehow you customized your tabs or you have a different version of Visual Studio, not Visual Studio Code. I am talking about Visual Studio. Also you can access the same options under Debug->Options->Environment->Keyboard

Comment: Thanks a lot. I set it to ctrl+/.

Comment: This is not working in Visual Studio Enterprise 2022.

Answer (score 5):

In Visual Studio Code that is called **Toggle Block Comments**

By default command is **Shift + Alt + A**

But you can customize as your own in Visual Studio Code. I did it **ctrl + shift + /**

Hope it might help

Answer (score 2):

To comment a block of code (more than one line) in VS 
select code with ALT (alt+mouse or alt+shift+arrows), and then comment with Ctrl+K Ctrl+C.
With one line code only you don't need ALT.

So it's basically the same as with // comments, only ALT needs to be pressed while selecting code for more lines than one.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio 2019 & 2022 support commenting a line with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>.

You can change it by modifying `Edit.ToggleBlockComment`.

If you change it to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>,
you may have to remove the shortcut for `EditorContextMenus.CodeWindow.GenerateDocumentationComments`, which uses the same keys.

Answer (score 1):

Shift + Option + A - figured it out by going to Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts and searching "comment"

Answer (score 1):

Using @mjwrazor example I did a slight variation, that worked.

I was working on a Wix .wxs file and was trying to easily comment in and out like VSCode..

In VS 2022 I went to

- Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard

In the box "Show Commands Containing" type "Comment" and add a shortcut keys as follows:

- Edit.CommentSelection (Fig. 1)

  - Set Global ShortCut - Ctrl + /
  - Click Assign
- Edit.UncommentSelection

  - Set Global ShortCut - Ctrl + Shift + /## Heading ##
  - Click Assign

Job done, sigh, why does VS not just use the VSCode shortcuts..
This has been bugging me for ages, hope this helps.

Fig 1
[image: Set Comment]
Fig 2
[image: Uncomment]

Answer (score 0):

You can now use 
**Ctrl** + **Shift** + **A**  /* for block comments */

And 
**Ctrl** + **ù**   // for line comments

Comment: this does not work