# Is it possible to mult-line comment in Kusto?

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer

I can definitely use "//" to comment every line, but was wondering if there was a way to do avoid doing this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

to date (2020-07-10) - that's not supported.

feature requests can be raised/upvoted @ https://aka.ms/adx.uservoice

Comment: Thanks for that information. Definitely going to upvote.

Comment: This seems to be the most voted on instance of this feature request: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/e6224411-ed24-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0

Answer (score 9):

The [visual studio keyboard shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32426267/visual-studio-comment-shortcut) for commenting (Ctrl+K+C) or uncommenting (Ctrl+K+U) multiple lines can be useful if you want to do it quickly. I have tested it on Web UI. Alternatively, if you are a Resharper user, you can also use Ctrl+/

Comment: Yes. But in Kusto or Azure Data Explorer, you cannot do that at this time. This can only be done in VS or VS Code.

Comment: commenting (Ctrl+K+C) or uncommenting (Ctrl+K+U) works for me!

Comment: As of March 2023, I can use Ctrl+/ on the Web UI to comment and uncomment line(s).